# Рассчитать и вывести сумму всех цифр введённого числа

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
h = 0
while n>0:
  a = n%10
  h = h +a
  n//10
  print(h)
```

Почему код не выводит сумму?

Comment: Тут бесконечно прибавляется последняя цифра числа. Всё работает ровно так, как Вы написали в коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n//10
```

но нет присваивания `n`, сделайте

```
n //= 10
```

кроме того `print(h)` выведите не внутри цикла, а снаружи

итого:

```
n = int(input())

h = 0
while n>0:
  a = n % 10
  h = h +a
  n //= 10

print(h)
```

кроме того стоит учесть, что ввести могут и отрицательные числа, т.е. лучше сделать

```
n = abs(int(input()))
```

**P.S.**

но это же питон, тут многое можно сделать в 1 строчку :)

```
res = sum(map(int, input()))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ella.erokhina, добавил однострочный вариантик :)